# Android ChangeCameraOnFly

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I want to be able to switch the camera from back to front (or from front to back)
With this code when I launch the app, the first switch works but others don't :

```
  public void changeCameraOnFly(View v)
  {
       if (isPreview) {camera.stopPreview();}
       camera.release();

           System.out.println("Camera ID before : " + String.valueOf(cameraID));
       if(cameraID == 0) {cameraID++;}
       if(cameraID == 1) {cameraID--;}
       System.out.println("Camera ID after: " + String.valueOf(cameraID));

           camera = Camera.open(cameraID);
           try {
                //this step is critical or preview on new camera will no know where to render to
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceCamera.getHolder());
           }
           catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
       camera.startPreview();
  }
```

Debug log :

```
06-17 18:27:43.594: I/System.out(10551): Camera ID before : 1
06-17 18:27:43.594: I/System.out(10551): Camera ID after: 0
06-17 18:27:46.074: I/System.out(10551): Camera ID before : 0
06-17 18:27:46.074: I/System.out(10551): Camera ID after: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `cameraId` is 0, your first if statement is true. Thus `cameraId` is incremented to 1.

Then your application continues to the next line, where you check if `cameraId` is 1. Indeed it is, so `cameraId` is decremented back to 0.

Try using an if-else instead. For example:

```
if (cameraId == 0) {
    cameraId++;
} else if (cameraId == 1) {
    cameraId--;
} else {
    // Default: Do nothing
}
```

Comment: I added one suggested fix to my answer.

Comment: Tha was so easy in fact --' Thanks a lot ;)